# My dlookup function made my MS access database slow

Tags: sql, ms-access, dlookup

is there any function instead of Dlookup to fast my database?
here is my code:

```
Me.txtMacroDispTest1.Value = DLookup("[TestNo]", "tblmetallurgy8", _
"[FirstArticleNumber] = '" & Me.txtFirstArticlenumber & "' and [TestNoID] = 1")
```

I want to display the value for the textbox from the table field [TestNo], condition to satisfy is based on number [ ie: FirstArticleNumber] and other field value will 1 [ie: TestNoID]

can anyone help me to speedup the code ?

Answer (score 1):

If this is in a continuous form, then you will be running that query (DLookup is a query at it's most basic level) for every record.

If it's a single form then a single DLookup shouldn't be that slow to run.

On the continuous form, If possible add the lookup as a joined table to your forms underlying query, and it will only need to perform the query once for the whole dataset.

Finally, check that the fields you are referencing are indexed.